# Could this be the toughest armor?

Tags: science-fiction, physics

I am making a character that has all his body’s natural abilities increased about 300-fold and I am trying to produce a distinctive suite of Frog Mouth full plate mail that makes sense for his build as a holier than thou, in your face fighter type. I am toying with the idea of making the armor out of alloy of 35% osmium, 35% Tungsten, and 30% out of some type of a shock resistant steel, then have the whole thing etched in holy ichnography and gilded in gold.

```
 The idea is that the Osmium and Tungsten would provide the armor with a level of density and hardness that would make it exceedingly difficult to penetrate while the steel would hopefully mitigate the tendency of Osmium and Tungsten to shatter and crack when struck wrong. As for the icons and gold, that’s just character flavor. 

My problem is I am neither a metallurgist nor a smith. **My question is whether an armor could even be made from this alloy and if it would be tough enough to make most medieval style melee weapons useless, even against other super humans**
```

Comment: Hi Grant, welcome to world building. You might benefit for searching a bit about medieval armor, and the weapons and tactics made to counter it. Making a truly perfect armor is impossible without magic, because even if you just encased yourself in the alloy, you'd still be vulnerable to kinetic energy, and an armor that allows you to move and see inevitably needs to have joints and gaps in it. In fights against knights, a prepared combatant would rely on weapons specifically made to counter armor (warhammers and polearms come to mind) and/or attack the joints and openings to just bypass it.

Comment: I know, I even know a few great spells for this issue from a few other series I have read that combine science and magic. My favorite is the one that distributes all kinetic energy exterily generated evenly throughout every molecule of the armor until it reaches an unsafe threshold and even store small amounts of kinetic energy in magic batteries to boost the user's movements. I just what to try and get the material part of it down as much as possible before I focus on the magic. I am also trying to avoid hand waving the problem away be using fictitious materials.

Comment: When asking if it could be made, do you ask if it could be made using current or near-future technology, or with medieval tech only? Should we consider the armor to be a normal knight one in terms of shape and size? I ask because keeping the same shape visually means your character could wear quite a bit more with 300x more strength.

Comment: I see. One possible reason for the downvotes may be because this isn't as specific as it might seem at first, especially with your level system. For example: who is wielding the medieval weapons? Nonmagical Armor that might resist several strikes from a polearm wielded by a peasant will not resist as well to the same ploearm wielded by a superhuman 200 times stronger than your average person. The existence of such a wide-spread leveling system can easily change nearly everything about your society, and be a major factor in how it works, and thus this question becomes a bit too broad.

Comment: Also something to think upon : if all their natural capacities are multiplied by 300x, it probably means that they're ultra-resistant naturally, too. At this point, I bet that they would gain less with a weak -relatively to them- armor in place of dodging incoming nuke strikes with their improved speed/reaction time :). All of this is true if and only if they're indeed much more resilient.

Comment: Another thing to consider: you want the armor to be tough  so it will be very hard to penetrate, with measurements to mitigate shattering, but when you're wearing armor, you're doing so to protect yourself, and a harder armor that might still shatter if struck "wrong" with enough force is overall not ideal. Steel has the quality of being both strong and malleable, meaning rather than shattering, it usually deforms, a vital quality when most weapons made to counter armor are specifically designed to apply massive force in a small area, making use of Kinetic energy to harm the wearer.

Comment: What are your suggestions then on how to format the question? I thought it was a simple enough metallurgical query. Should I just remove all the background info on the level system and only aske about the alloy?

Comment: To Tortliena, I am asking if it can be made with mostly magically enhanced privative forging techniques.  This world has advanced metallurgical knowledge, but the advance of magic has caused both a lag in technological revolution and a great difference in technology on a regional basis. Some areas have forging at the early medieval period, others at the late Revolutionary.

Comment: I suggest taking a step back. Go back to the basic question: what is the armor for? In this case, the answer is protection, but from what? Does it only need to deal with peasants with rocks and hammers or does it need to handle a superhuman packing a punch with the power of a rifle bullet? What kind of weapons does it need to protect against? Once you understand what your armor needs to be able to handle, searching how we dealt with similar demands in the real world might give you a better clue. Maybe just making a thicker armor with modern steel proves better than any special osmium alloy.

Comment: Or go down the shadiversity (really recommend it, a great YouTube channel) and do as he did in his book: instead of relying on strong metals with enchantments, make the metals strong *through* enchantments. Depending on how magic works, you could have a light and breathable  ornate armor that far outranks even the best natural alloys, and that without needing to worry about scratching the gold details. Your BBEG is level 1200, if they got this far, they probably have access to some pretty ample resources, maybe even some forbidden or lost methods.

Comment: Could you please break the wall of text up into readable chunks to make it easier on our membership. Reducing it to a single clear question would help quite a bit to get it reopened.

Comment: Could you just format it normally rather than making it unreadable on mobile devices. More detail needed as to the use conditions an requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alloys don't work like that**

[image]

When you combine two metals you do not simply combine their strengths and weaknesses. Bronze is stronger and has a higher melting point than both tin and copper. The most well-known allow, steel, is just iron with less than 1% carbon incorporated. But the manner the carbon is incorporated is important.

The properties of the alloy come from the way the different molecules are arranged at the microscopic level.

Sometimes the strength comes from the irregular arrangement of molecules. Which of the two walls look stronger to you. This one?

[image]

Or this one?

[image]

The first one is the pure metal. The second is the alloy. The bricks/molecules are jumbled up so there is no way to just tear a stack off the wall.

Most mixtures of metals give bad alloys. We don't use those. We don't have names for them. There is no reason to believe osmium, tungsten, and steel melt together into anything useful.

For flavour I suggest you have the metal be 99% steel imbued with 1% osmium. That sounds more like a real alloy. Of course there is still not reason to believe that particular alloy would work. But it sounds slightly closer to reality.

For extra points don't call it osmium. Medieval people did not know about osmium. If they had some they would have called it something different. Call it Gravis Ore because it is heavy. Call it Core Metal. Call it St Thauberdine's Folly. Call it Tin of Ill Repute. Describe it as looking like osmium, and leave the identity as an Easter Egg for the Reader.

But really, since you have people who are somehow 300 times faster, stronger, better, and more attractive than real people, why bother trying to explain the armor in real terms at all?

Do not worry about stretching disbelief -- it was shattered long ago. Just stick your baddie in a set of full plate with an Enchantment of Fortification Degree 1200. The kind only a high level Wizard or Artificier can cast. Then be done with it.

Comment: Absolutely. The recent alloying debacle in *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power* 
is misleading.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I have not seen The Rings of Power. I m not ready for Middle Earth without Hugo Weaving.

Comment: I like the idea, especially the part about the easter egg, but do you think have the ratio for the alloy so skewed is such a good idea? 1% sounds really low?

Comment: @GrantPflum [It is the same sort of ratio for carbon/iron when making steel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_steel)

Comment: Yeah but that just adding a small amount of carbon to iron. To make Bronze one needs 88% copper to 12% tin. If the goal of the alloy is to gain some of the properties of the osmium without losing the steels properties is 1% really enough? Or am I just overthinking it?

Comment: @GrantPflum As I said, that is not how allows work. Bronze is stronger than both copper and tin. It has a higher melting point than both copper and thin. You cannot tell what the alloy will be like by looking at the constituent metals. You have to look at the constituent metal atoms and how they like to fit together. That is why steel is much harder and brittle than iron despite being 99% the same stuff.